# How to create a 3D (shape=m,n,o) array with ones along a specific (third) axis, the indices are given by a 2D array (shape=m,n)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Let us say I have a 2D array with a shape (2, 2), containing indices

```
x = np.array([[2, 0], [3, 1]])
```

What I would like to do is to create a 3D array with a shape (2, 2, 4), which has values 1 along the third axis, and their position is given by `x`, therefore:

```
y = np.zeros(shape=(2,2,4))
myfunc(array=y, indices=x, axis=2)

array([[[0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0]],
       [[0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0]]])
```

So far I have not found any indexing method for this. A `for` loop might be able to do this, but I am sure there is a faster, vectorized method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `for` loops:

```
y = np.zeros(shape=(2,2,4))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        y[i,j,x[i,j]] = 1
```

With advanced indexing:

```
y = np.zeros(shape=(2,2,4))
i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(2), np.arange(2))
y[i,j,x[i,j]] = 1
```

Output (in both cases):

```
array([[[0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.]]])
```

As for which will be actually faster, you need to try on your exact case...

Comment: Thanks! As my array will be rather big, I tend to use  the meshgrid approach.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). To index with integer arrays properly, you need to have a set of arrays that broadcast to the right shape. Since `x` is already lined up with two of the dimensions, you only need to make 2D arrays with the indices along each axis. [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) helps with that since it creates minimal range arrays that broadcast to the correct shape:

```
a, b = np.ogrid[:2, :2]
y[a, b, x] = 1
```

The results of `ogrid` are equivalent to

```
a = np.arange(2).reshape(-1, 1)
b = np.arange(2).reshape(1, -1)
```

Or

```
a = np.arange(2)[:, None]
b = np.arange(2)[None, :]
```

You can also write a one-liner:

```
y[(*tuple(slice(None, n) for n in x.shape), x)] = 1
```

Comment: Who doesn't love those obscure cryptic python one-liners! :)

Comment: @Julien. They're fun to write and I always try to post one in my answers if at all possible. I don't recommend actually using them though.

Comment: Nice, is this one faster than the aforementioned meshgrid with larger arrays?

Comment: @Commander. Probably somewhat. The only difference is that it allocates 2x1, 1x2 instead of a pair of 2x2 indices.